# mvn scm: Execute scm:diff as a goal in my project

Tags: maven

I want to create a diff file in my build with the mvn-scm-plugin. I have configured the scm connection (I only need the local repo)

```
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:file:/.git</connection>
  </scm>
```

When I use mvn scm:diff it does indeed create a diff file as I expect.

The [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/) says that each command is implemented as a goal. I would like to include scm:diff as a goal to be executed in my build when I run
mvn install.

This is the configuration for the scm-plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>scm-diff</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>diff</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>compile</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

However, when I run mvn install, there is no diff file created. Am I mistaken to expect this to be possible, or is it just a matter of +wrong configuration?

Comment: For what purpose do you like to create it via Maven? What is so complicated on `git diff ..`?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I would like to create the diff file that another custom plugin in my build would later use.
The build will always be run with "maven install" on a Jenkins server that I don't have permissions to modify.

Comment: What is the intention of that? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?